# Indexed currency column in custom list not showing currency symbol when mapped

Tags: 2013

I have a custom list which has an indexed currency column called Price. I crawled the list and have a crawled property of Ows_q_CURR_Price which I mapped to a refinablestring for a content search web part.

Instead of getting £10.50 I get 10.5000000000000 and I've searched and searched and cannot work out how to get the £ sign and 2 decimals to show which is how that column is set up.

I've tried ows_price and get just the number and still no currency symbol.  I'm using Sharepoint 2013.

Any help or ideas would be greatly received.

Comment: same problem here...